# Unable to create files with threads in C

Tags: c, file-io, pthreads

I wrote a program to create a number of files using pthread. for example, if I pass "./ioload 1 10", this program should create 10 files (namely output0, output1, ..., output9) that takes in total 1MB of disk space. However, when I ran the program, it was not able to create all 10 files after execution. I am wondering that what could cause this issue?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int numOfThreads;
int sizeOfDisk;
int blockSize = 4096;


void *write(void *name)
{
     FILE * fd;
     char fname[100];
     strcpy(fname,"output");
     strcat(fname, (char *)name);
     int fileSize = sizeOfDisk * 1024 * 1024 / blockSize / numOfThreads; 
     char block[fileSize];
     memset(block, 0, sizeof(*block));

     int i;
     fd = fopen(fname, "w");

     if (NULL == fd)
     {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: FAILED TO OPEN FILE %s\n", fname);
        return NULL;
     }

     for (i = 0; i < fileSize; i++)
        fwrite(block, sizeof(blockSize), 4096, fd);

     fclose(fd);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s sizeOfDiskInMB #OfThreads\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    sizeOfDisk = atoi(argv[1]);
    numOfThreads = atoi(argv[2]);

    pthread_t ths[numOfThreads];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < numOfThreads; i++)
    {
        char ibuffer [100];
        snprintf(ibuffer, sizeof(ibuffer), "%d", i);

        if (pthread_create(&ths[i], NULL, write, (void *)&ibuffer)) 
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: FAILD TO CREATE THREAD %d", i);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < numOfThreads; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(ths[i], 0);
    }

}
```

Comment: `memset(block, 0, sizeof(*block));` is wrong, it should be `memset(block,0,sizeof(block)` or `memset(block,0,fileSize)`

Answer (score 3):

Every thread is passed a pointer to `ibuffer`.  It is very possible that `ibuffer` has the same address for every iteration of the main thread's loop, meaning that all threads are trying to read from the same memory.

There is no guarantee that each new thread will be scheduled and will get as far as creating its file before your main thread starts its next iteration of its loop, updating the content of `ibuffer`.  This may leave several threads trying to create the same file or some threads trying to read their file name in the middle of a later `snprintf` call.

To fix this, you either need to have each thread signal that it has completed construction or store an array of file names in the main thread, passing a pointer to a different instance into each thread.

```
void *write(void *name)
{
    FILE * fd;
    char fname[100];
    snprintf(fname, sizeof(fname), "output%d", *(int*)name);
    ...


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    ....
    pthread_t ths[numOfThreads];
    int fileNum[numOfThreads];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numOfThreads; i++)
    {
        fileNum[i] = i;
        if (pthread_create(&ths[i], NULL, write, (void *)&fileNum[i])) 
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: FAILD TO CREATE THREAD %d", i);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    ....
```

Comment: in your write function, there is no i, I think you meant `*(int *)name`

Answer (score 0):

Thank-you for this question, have developed threads in C#, so this was a good review on implementing C/Win32 threads.

First caveat is that this code was written for a Windows machine using a Microsoft C compiler.  For *nix systems you will need to do something similar, but the call and macro names are different.  However, the general principle is the same.

1. Create a storage area that is unique for each thread.  Place thread specific
   info. into this area.
2. Initiate a thread, pass it this area, as well as the size of its
   stack (in MS land as  0 size gives the thread the same size stack as
   the process.
3. in `main()` after initiating all the threads, wait for them to
   complete.  Use a semaphore to test for completion.

For Windows you need to use thread-safe libraries but it looks like any system from XP and above provides thread safe DLLs like `msvcrt.lib`.  Also, there is a `_begintheadex` version that has even more features and is recommended.

Finally, this code is NOT ready for use in a real application.  There is still a lot of stuff that it should do (like using `_beginthreadex`), but for the purposes of discussion this is a good start.

```
// Compiled on Eclipse/Microsoft C Compiler
// compile with: /MT /D "_X86_" /c
// processor: x86
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>    /* _beginthread, _endthread */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct ThreadParameterBlock
{
    int  threadNr;     //
    char fname[13];    // outputxx.bin\0
    int  numBlocks;    // expected number of blocks for this file
    int  blockSize;    // Number of bytes per block
    int  num_writes;   // actual number of writes
    char fill_char;    // for each byte
    clock_t  time_done;
    int  thread_done;  // 1 is running, 0 is stopped

};

void A_Writing_Thread(struct ThreadParameterBlock *TPB)
{
     // each thread has its own stack
     FILE *fd;

     int i;

     char *block;

     block = (char *) malloc(TPB->blockSize);
     if (block != NULL)
     {
       memset(block, TPB->fill_char, TPB->blockSize);

       fd = fopen(TPB->fname, "w");

       if (NULL == fd)
       {
          fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: FAILED TO OPEN FILE %s\n", TPB->fname);
       } else {

           for (i = 0; i < TPB->numBlocks; i++)
           {
              // to help demo parallelism of threads,
              // some threads run slow
              if (i%10 == 0)
              {
                  if (TPB->threadNr == 1)     {Sleep(50L);}
                  if ((TPB->threadNr%2) == 0) {Sleep(100L);}
                  if ((TPB->threadNr%3) == 0) {Sleep(200L);}
                  // glad I'm NOT thread 6!
              }
              fwrite(block, sizeof(TPB->blockSize), 1, fd);
              TPB->num_writes++;
           }

       }

       if (fd != NULL) {fclose(fd);}

       free(block);
     }

     printf("\nThread %d done.", TPB->threadNr);

     TPB->time_done   = clock();
     // only exit is thru this code...
     // thread done
     TPB->thread_done = 1;

     _endthread();
}

main()
{

    int numOfThreads = 0;
    int sizeOfDisk = 0;

    int nr_blocks;

    int thread_done_count;

    int blockSize = 4096;

    char ch = 'A';

    int i;

    // allow up to 10 threads
    struct ThreadParameterBlock *thread_array[10];
    struct ThreadParameterBlock *TPB;

    printf("Enter: Size of Disk(MB) white_space  number_of_threads press enter :");
    fflush(stdout);

    scanf("%d %d", &sizeOfDisk, &numOfThreads);

    if (sizeOfDisk < 0)  {sizeOfDisk = 1;}
    if (sizeOfDisk > 10) {sizeOfDisk = 10;}

    if (numOfThreads < 0)  {numOfThreads = 1;}
    if (numOfThreads > 10) {numOfThreads = 10;}

    nr_blocks = (sizeOfDisk * 1024 * 1024) / (numOfThreads * blockSize);
    printf("\ncreating %d threads to allocate %d blocks of 4096 bytes, per thread/file.\n",
                  numOfThreads, nr_blocks);
    fflush(stdout);

    for (i = 0; i < numOfThreads; i++)
    {
        thread_array[i] = TPB = (struct ThreadParameterBlock *)
                                    malloc(sizeof(struct ThreadParameterBlock));

        TPB->threadNr    = i + 1;
        TPB->time_done   = 0;
        TPB->thread_done = 0;
        TPB->numBlocks   = nr_blocks;
        TPB->blockSize   = blockSize;
        TPB->num_writes  = 0;
        TPB->fill_char   = ch++;
        sprintf(TPB->fname, "output%02d.bin", i+1);

        printf("\nstarting thread %d", i+1);
        fflush(stdout);

        /* On first loops, launch character threads. */
        _beginthread(A_Writing_Thread, 0, thread_array[i]);

    }

    // essentially a join...
    while (1)
    {
       /* Wait one second between polls of threads */
       Sleep( 250L );

       thread_done_count = 0;
       for (i = 0; i < numOfThreads; i++)
       {
           thread_done_count += thread_array[i]->thread_done;
       }

       if (thread_done_count >= numOfThreads) {break;}

    }

    printf("\nAll threads are done.");

    printf("\n\nThread Summary");
    for (i = 0; i < numOfThreads; i++)
    {
        printf("\nThread %2d completed %4d writes(%dkB) at %5d to <%s>.",         thread_array[i]->threadNr,
                thread_array[i]->num_writes,
                (thread_array[i]->num_writes*thread_array[i]->blockSize) / 1024,
                thread_array[i]->time_done,
                thread_array[i]->fname);

        // free parameter block for thread i
        free(thread_array[i]);
    }

} // end main;
```

Hope this helps.  Please ask if more questions.